# Make photo popups

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make these photos popup onclick. The photos are being pulled from two directories. The first photos you see are from the thumbs directory, and I want to display the full photo from the originals directory when the thumb is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$images_dir = 'images/med/full/';
$thumbs_dir = 'images/med/thumb/';
$thumbs_width = 300;
$thumbs_height = 300;
$images_per_row = 3;

/** generate photo gallery **/
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
if(count($image_files)) {
$index = 0;
foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
    $index++;
    $thumbnail_image = $thumbs_dir.$file;
    if(!file_exists($thumbnail_image)) {
        $extension = get_file_extension($thumbnail_image);
        if($extension) {
            make_thumb  ($images_dir.$file,$thumbnail_image,$thumbs_width,$thumbs_height);
        }
    }
    echo '<a href="',$images_dir.$file,'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',$thumbnail_image,'" /></a>';
    if($index % $images_per_row == 0) { echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; }
}
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else {
    echo '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
}

?>
```

I was using [Smoothbox](http://gueschla.com/labs/smoothbox/smoothbox.js), but I wasn't able to get it to work. I was hoping I could write a smaller script instead of using the one from the link above.

I've researched creating a simple lightbox such as [this one here](http://tonylea.com/2011/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-lightbox/), but I'm not sure how to integrate it with my code above.

Here is the link to the website with my photos I want this to work on: http://davishosting.net/ginger/mediterranean

I'm very new to PHP and I really enjoy learning the coding language! I've been studying very hard to get this far. I would like the photo to enlarge and center, with a semi transparent background over everything behind it. I'm familiar with using `rgba` in CSS to make the transparent backgrounds.